# How to display a storedinstance from sql on BLL.cs onto a WPF page for c# program?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on the UI for a C# program in WPF. How do I take the `Store.StoreInstance` of the person who logs into the program to display his/her name/other info onto a `TextBlock` on a WPF page? The user info is pulled from the SQL database.

```
if (list.Count > 0)
{
    Store.StoreInstance.diner = list[0];
    Debug.WriteLine(list.First().displayName);                    
}
```

This code is in the `BLL.cs`
I am trying to display this user into his/her WPF `homepage.xaml` into this `TextBlock` inside the `USERNAMETEXTPLACEHOLDER`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="userhome" Text="USERNAMETEXTPLACEHOLDER" Height="90" FontSize="25" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 -20" Foreground="{StaticResource Foreground.Hover}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the code behind xaml file `homepage.xaml.cs`, use the following snippet:

```
if (userhome != null)
{
    userhome.Text = displayName;
}
```

But how to get `displayName` from the BLL to this code behind file? The usual way is to emit an event from the BLL, which is subscribed from the code behind (i.e. view layer). Pull the string out of the event and set into the variable `displayName`, and use the code shown above to display it in the TextBlock control.

Comment: Where do I place the IF statement inside the homepage.xaml.cs? I know that buttons have click event handlers where I can right click and go to the definition and write code inside, but how about textblock? Do I manually create a method for it? I am still fairly new to c#. This is for a whole class project and I am mainly only working on the xaml and xaml.cs portions. I am not in charge of the BLL.cs, but I do have access to it. Code wise I did not work on any of the BLL

Comment: Typically you will put this snippet inside an event handler in the code behind file. Typically it will be a handler for a UI event, such as the click handler for a button. So exactly which handler to use depends on when you want to update the textblock. Here is a list of common events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview